rackslab/slurm-web can't vertify the user through openldap
slurm-web comes from the project https://github.com/rackslab/Slurm-web
When i configure authentication with openldap, and i use user/password as authentication, the login web page always says " ERROR,Authentication error: Invalid user or password"
However, i use /usr/libexec/slurm-web/slurm-web-ldap-check command, it runs ok, here's the answer
INFO ⸬ Running slurm-web-ldap-check
Found 2 user(s) in LDAP directory:
- hslurm (hello_slurm) [acoustic, physic]
- jgreen (jim_green) [acoustic, biology]

then I'll paste some configuration in gateway.ini
[authentication]
enabled=yes
method=ldap

[ldap]
uri=ldap://192.169.1.225
bind_dn=cn=admin,dc=s5,dc=localdomain
bind_password=slap123
user_base=ou=People,dc=s5,dc=localdomain
group_base=ou=Group,dc=s5,dc=localdomain
user_class=posixAccount

Through the openldap.log I knew the difference, but I don't know why the web page can't use the same procedure as the test command slurm-web-ldap-check
Here's the slurm-web-ldap-check log message:
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=172.19.129.231:55372 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" method=128
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" mech=SIMPLE bind_ssf=0 ssf=0
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 qtime=0.000054 etime=0.004250 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=1 SRCH base="ou=People,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=posixAccount)"
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=1 SRCH attr=uid
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000033 etime=0.001014 nentries=2 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=2 SRCH base="cn=hello_slurm,ou=People,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=posixAccount)"
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=2 SRCH attr=cn gidNumber
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000084 etime=0.000493 nentries=1 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=3 SRCH base="ou=Group,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(objectClass=groupOfNames))(|(memberUid=hslurm)(member=cn=hello_slurm,ou=people,dc=s5,dc=localdomain)(gidNumber=500)))"
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=3 SRCH attr=cn
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000067 etime=0.000414 nentries=2 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=4 SRCH base="cn=jim_green,ou=People,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=posixAccount)"
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=4 SRCH attr=cn gidNumber
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000028 etime=0.000208 nentries=1 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=5 SRCH base="ou=Group,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(objectClass=groupOfNames))(|(memberUid=jgreen)(member=cn=jim_green,ou=people,dc=s5,dc=localdomain)(gidNumber=501)))"
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=5 SRCH attr=cn
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=5 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 qtime=0.000019 etime=0.000277 nentries=2 text=
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 op=6 UNBIND
Jun 21 15:27:48 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1049 fd=13 closed

While the login web page has the log message:
Jun 21 15:29:14 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1050 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=172.19.129.231:60966 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Jun 21 15:29:14 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1050 op=0 BIND dn="uid=jgreen,ou=People,dc=s5,dc=localdomain" method=128
Jun 21 15:29:14 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1050 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=49 qtime=0.000055 etime=0.000669 text=
Jun 21 15:29:14 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1050 op=1 UNBIND
Jun 21 15:29:14 s5 slapd[534541]: conn=1050 fd=13 closed

Here's the version i use slurm-web
python3-slurm-web-3.0.0-1.el9.noarch
slurm-web-agent-3.0.0-1.el9.noarch
slurm-web-gateway-3.0.0-1.el9.noarch

I even tried that openldap whether work ok in httpd(apache 2.4), however, when i use browser it show the login window and the user/password work normally.
so i don't know how to change the procedure of web login to work well as the test command, do anybody give me some clues, since i didn't find how it work

Here's some userguide page https://docs.rackslab.io/slurm-web/install/quickstart.html

here's the answer https://github.com/rackslab/Slurm-web/discussions/310

I figured it out: first you have to upgrade your slurm-web to 3.1 version.
More details at Slurm web discussion #310
